# find conservative regions relative to a specific accession

Tags: multiple-sequence-alignment

I have 7 `RefSeq` accessions which I performed `multiple sequence aligment` on it using `CLUSTALO`. These are the following:

```
NC_026431.1
NC_007363.1
NC_004907.1
NC_007377.1
NC_007367.1
NC_002016.1
NC_026427.1
```

I input the fasta sequence of those 7 accessions on `CLUSTALO` under this [link](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/msa/clustalo/). I get the result in either the `msf` format or `clustal` format with characters. The result looks like the following:

```
CLUSTAL O(1.2.4) multiple sequence alignment


NC_002016.1      -------AGCGAAAGCAGGTAGATATTGAAAGATGAGTCTTCTAACCGAGGTCGAAACGT   53
NC_007377.1      -------AGCAAAAGCAGGTAGATATTGAAAGATGAGCCTTCTAACCGAGGTCGAAACGT   53
NC_007367.1      -------AGCAAAAGCAGGTAGATATTGAAAGATGAGCCTTCTAACCGAGGTCGAAACGT   53
NC_004907.1      GGGGAATTCCAAAAGCAGGTAGATATTGAAAGATGAGTCTTCTAACCGAGGTCGAAACGT   60
NC_026427.1      --------------------------------ATGAGTCTTCTAACCGAGGTCGAAACGT   28
NC_007363.1      -------AGCAAAAGCAGGTAGATATTGAAAAATGAGTCTTCTAACCGAGGTCGAAACGT   53
NC_026431.1      --------------------------------ATGAGTCTTCTAACCGAGGTCGAAACGT   28
                                                 ***** **********************
```

I'm aware that the `*` symbols means a highly conserved region and that's exatcly what I'm looking for , however I need the highly conserved regions relative to a specific accession, namely `NC_007367.1`. I'm not sure how to do that. I'm also not sure what the `-` represents.

Comment: https://www.ddbj.nig.ac.jp/faq/en/explain-three-symbols-e.html, https://abacus.bates.edu/bioinformatics1/clustalw2.html. **"highly conserved" is probably not an accurate way to judge "*".** All it means is that the position aligns perfectly across the input sequences, there is no statement about conservation or other evolutionary phenomena. clustal is only an alignment program.

Comment: thanks, what would be the tool to find the conservative region then ? since CLUSTAL just gives a similarity estimation.

Comment: THere are various tools- depends a bit what your goal is in finding these positions. Simple visualizations that emphasize relative stability in alignments, e.g. here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3226196/. Gblocks is a somewhat more disciplined statistical approach, I am still unsure if it is exactly what you want: https://academic.oup.com/mbe/article/17/4/540/1127654, webserver here: http://molevol.cmima.csic.es/castresana/Gblocks_server.html

Answer (score 2):

You can opt for a similarity matrix as output ([here is an example](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/46049/how-to-interpret-percent-identity-matrix-created-by-clustal-omega)). The fact that you would like to judge conservation "relative to a given sequence", you can use this matrix to rank similarities of different sequences with respect to any of these sequences.

I would advise visualizing these similarities, for example in terms of a heatmap, and seeing if anything stands out (with respect to your sequence of interest). And I would advise against selecting an arbitrary threshold (i.e. 90% or 95%), this would trigger questions based on the selection criteria of such a cutoff and this is understandable, such arbitrary cut-offs often do not mean much in biology.